# C# XmlSerializer: Deserialize empty GUID value from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have a configuration file which contains XML like this:

```
<XmlParameter Title="Analysis">
    <ProcedureName>XmlParameterAnalysisGetFirst</ProcedureName>
    <ProcedureGroupId/>
    <Returns>Table</Returns>
    <Params>
        <Param OrderKey="0" Name="xmlParameters">%xmlParameters%</Param>
    </Params>
</XmlParameter>
```

I use the `XmlSerializer` class to deserialize the file during runtime into an object of type `XmlParameter`:

```
public class XmlParameter {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string ProcedureName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]
    public Guid? ProcedureGroupId { get; set; }

    public string Returns { get; set; }

    public List<XmlCLRParam> Params { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to deserialize the file with this code block:

```
var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlParameter);
var reader = new StreamReader(this.FilePath);
var obj  = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

I get an `System.InvalidOperationException`:

> Error in XML-Document. ---> Sytem.Format.Exception: Unknown Guid-format.

My question is whether there is a way to deserialize `nullable` GUID values from the XML-file

Comment: To simplify your problem don't use a nullable Guid instead use Guid.Empty. This equals to 0000-000... which isn't a valid Guid so it's fine to be checked against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nullable means the POCO field will get a null reference if there is no present in the xml file...

you have your xml wrongly formatted: remove this:

> < ProcedureGroupId/>